# Change template in Wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, templates, plugins, themes

I want to detect if the subdomain is "m.", and if so display a different template.  Couldn't find what I was looking for, in the Wordpress API to do so.

Comment: If you want to *temporarily* use a different template on the active HTTP request, you want the [`template_include` filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include). If you want to *persist* the change so it's used on all future requests, you need to directly update the `template` and `stylesheet` options in the `wp_options` table. Note that [`template` and `stylesheet` are not identical](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/40220/10388).

Comment: See also [switch_theme()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/switch_theme/). Lots of different options, it appears. I'm figuring this out along with you guys! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [parse_url()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function in PHP to do this:

```
$parsed = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
$host = explode('.', $parsedUrl['host']);
$subdomain = $host[0];
```

Then, you can add your own if statement:

```
if ($subdomain == "m") { ... } else { ... }
```

Comment: Looking for like `wp_switch_template('theme_name');`  =3

Comment: That doesn't exist as far as I know. Just load a different stylesheet in the header using the IF statement above, or if it's more complicated than that, you might want to consider just using WP's network/multisite feature.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the 'template_redirect' filters, or one of the other _template filters to change the template thats being loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to create you own plugin with one single script and put it in wp-content/plugins with a code like this:

```
<?php
/**
* Plugin Name: Theme swithwer
* Plugin URI: http://URI_Of_Page_Describing_Plugin_and_Updates
* Description: Custom theme switcher
* Version: 0.1
* Author: XXX XXX
* Author URI: http://URI_Of_The_Plugin_Author
* License: A "Slug" license name e.g. GPL2
*/

add_filter( 'stylesheet', 'switch_ma_theme' );
add_filter( 'template',   'switch_ma_theme' );

function switch_ma_theme()

{
   global $wpdb;
   // condition to test ad theme to load
   if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'blog.xxxx.xxx')
       return 'xxxthemexxx';
   // else default theme
   $theme = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT option_value FROM wp_options where    option_name='template' ");
   $theme = array_pop($theme);
   return $theme->option_value;
   // Return the theme directory name

}
```

Then go in the admin , look for you new plugin and enable it